# CSS grid with components taking up variable number of squares

Tags: css, css-grid

In the attached picture, each colour / number represents a div inside of the grid. I understand how to create a situation like that of Grid A where each div takes up 1 square. How do I create a grid like that of Grid B, where each div takes up a variable number of squares?

[image]

Comment: Not possible with CSS-Grid...all grid spaces MUST be rectangles so in Grid B - 2 & 4 are not possible.

Comment: I see both grid the same. The only difference is that in B you have *similar* divs taking different cells